# Rails 5 set has_one association with strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, has-one

I am developing a Rails 5 application in which I encountered the following difficulty.

I've got two models, let's say `Kid` and `Toy`, which are in one-to-one relationship like this:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :toy
end

class Toy
  belongs_to :kid, optional: true
end
```

So the `toys` can belong to zero or one `kid`, and from day to day it can change - it is always another `kid`'s responsibility to look after a certain `toy`. Now, when I edit a `toy`, changing its `kid` is easy as can be: I just send `kid_id` in the strong params to update the record:

```
params.require(:toy).permit(:name, :type, :kid_id)
```

But recently, I was asked to implement the changing feature from the other way too, that is, when editing a kid, I should do something like this:

```
params.require(:kid).permit(:name, :age, :toy_id)
```

The problem is that - while `belongs_to` works with `association_id` and even `has_many` provides `association_ids` getter and setter - `has_one` relationship has nothing like this. What is more, `has_one` association gets saved the moment I call `association = @record`. So I simply cannot set it by sending the `toy_id` in the strong parameters.

I could do something like `@kid.update(kid_params); @kid.toy = @toy` on the controller level, but that would rather bring model logics to my controller, not to mention that I want to check if the newly assigned `toy` did not belong to another `kid`, which I imagine as some kind of validation.

The best I could come up with was to define some rails-like methods for `Kid` class like

```
def toy_id
  @toy_id = toy.id unless defined?(@toy_id)
  @toy_id
end

def toy_id_changed?
  toy_id != toy.id
end
```

and set a `validation` and a `before_commit` callback

```
validate if: -> { toy_id.present? && toy_id_changed? } do
  errors.add :toy_id, :other_has_it if new_toy.kid_id.present? && new_toy.kid_id != id
end
before_commit if: -> { toy_id_changed? } do
  toy = new_toy
end

private
def new_toy
  @new_toy ||= Toy.find(toy_id)
end
```

So far it works as expected, and now I can send `toy_id` in the strong params list to update a `kid`, and it updates the `toy` association if -
 and only if - there is no validation error. I have even put it in a concern to be nice and separated.

My question is: isn't there a rails way to do this? haven't I reinvented the wheel?

Thanks in advance!